# How can I trigger an event on page load in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The JavaScript library which I am using is loaded in the footer, so the React effect code does not have access to the analytics library and throws an error.

This is my code:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  // trigger event
}, []);
```

I am not sure how to track the analytics event.

I am using a component which returns some HTML. It does not have class otherwise I would use other React functions.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is limited in explanation.It would be good if you would have shared some more code.But I will answer as per my understanding of the question.

My understanding of question:You are getting some value from footer and based on that value you want to trigger some kind of event in your page.

So,this is how you should do it.

```
useEffect(()=>{
//Do some event after getting value
},[value which you get from footer]).
```

let me explain what i have written here.
First read a bit out useEffect.that would help you here.
Whatever value(just an example) you get from footer put it in a variable.Now use that variable in the useEffect depenedency array.

A basic example.

```
function demo(){
let a;
React.useEffect(()=>{
//do yourlogic here;
},[a]);
a=10;
```

in the above example whenever the value of a changes the useEffect will be triggered.

You can try similar approach.

Comment: How to get value from footer component when its loaded in page ?

Comment: There are multiple ways by which you can get the value from the <Footer/> into your <PageLoad />.
You can use a state management like Redux or React contextapi .So whenever the state (in your case footer value) changes ,it will also update the component where ever that state is consumed(in your case Page Load component).
Also,you can use props and pass the value from you <Footer/> to <PageLoad/>.But it might lead to Props drilling,which is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Using `useEffect()` is the correct way to run code which has side effects (such as making HTTP requests) whenever a component updates. CodeOfLife's answer shows you how to execute the effect code only once, and not for all subsequent component updates.

Analytics is usually a tricky part of development in the era of front-end frameworks, though. If you're hard-coding a `<script>` in your markup to load the main analytics script, it might make the most sense to just add another `<script>` just after it which tracks the event. If you want to track page view events on dynamic route changes (using a React router), you might need to send page view events in the router as well.

I'm sorry this answer is quite vague, but different analytics systems do things in different ways. You're probably finding you're trying to use the analytics system before it's loaded. You could use a delay to try and get around this, but it's very quick-and-dirty:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  let eventTracked = false;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // trigger event
    }, 500);
  }, [eventTracked]);
  eventTracked = true;
}
```